# JodaTime: Invalid format/malformed

Tags: java, jodatime

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Mon Jun 23 17:21:00 2014" is malformed at "Jun 23 17:21:00 2014"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:873)
    at PatternExample.startService(PatternExample.java:20)
    at PatternExample.main(PatternExample.java:36)
```

This is what gives the error:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E M d HH:mm:ss YYYY");
DateTime dateTime = formatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).parseDateTime("Mon Jun 23 17:21:00 2014");
System.out.println("DateTime: " + dateTime);
```

I followed the documentation for DateTimeFormat:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

The only thing to note is that this string time representation is in UTC, and it must be stored as a UTC datetime object. I know that there is a Z flag but it's not necessary here since I do not specify a timezone in the string.

E represents day of week (e.g. Mon). M represents month of year (e.g. Jun). d represents day of month (e.g. 23). And the time and year follow the documentation as well. Why am I getting this malformed error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `E` to `EEE` and `M` to `MMM` in your formatter string.